# Помогите составить регулярное выражение(0001_validation_messages.js => validation_messages)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Я пишу один скрипт на python и мне нужно получить только часть названия файла. Я понимаю, что это необязательно делать регулярными выражениями, но, подумал, что это может быть проще(но это не точно), а сам я в них не разбираюсь(хотя пора бы уже).

Пример:

```
0001_validation_messages.js => validation_messages
0008_honesty_questions_links.js => honesty_questions_links
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос:

```latex
^\d+_(.+)\.js$
```

Демострация:

```py
import re
name_list = [
    '0001_validation_messages.js',
    '0008_honesty_questions_links.js'
]

cmp = re.compile(r'^\d+_(.+)\.js$')
for item in name_list:
    print(
        cmp.sub(
            r'\1',
            item
        )
    )
# validation_messages
# honesty_questions_links
```